# Pokémon - Go exercise.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, coupon-collector

Imagine that at each time $n=1,2,...$ you find one of the $m$ Pokémon, assuming they all appear independently and uniformly at random. Let $R_0:=m$ and $R_n$ be the number of different Pokémon you still need to capture after time $n$ in order to complete your Pokédex.

1. Justify that conditionally on $R_n$, the random variable $R_n-R_{n-1}$ is Bernoulli(R_n/m) distributed.

I have no idea how to proceed. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: what is a Pokémon ?

Comment: See [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), as it's basically the same one. There several question on MSE about this. I added the tag to the question.

Comment: Thank you . Much appreciated!